# How do I prove that $P(A\cap B\cap C) ≥ P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - 2$?

Tags: probability

> $$P(A\cap B\cap C) ≥ P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - 2$$

Having a lot of difficulty with this one, would be grateful for any advice.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know the formula that determines the left hand probability?

Comment: @Alephnull No, never heard of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll prove it for $2$ variables, and try to generalize for three.

Given $P(A \cap B)$. We know that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B)-P(A \cup B)$. Hence, since $P(A \cup B) \leq 1$, it follows that $P(A \cap B) \geq P(A) + P(B)-1$.

Now, note that $P(A \cap B\ \cap C) = P((A \cap B)\cap C)$, so we can rewrite:
$$
P((A \cap B)\cap C) = P(A \cap B) + P(C) - P((A \cap B)\cup C)
$$

Note that $P(A \cap B) \geq P(A) + P(B)-1$, and $P((A \cap B) \cup C) \leq 1$, so that:
$$
P((A \cap B)\cap C) = P(A \cap B) + P(C) - P((A \cap B)\cup C) \geq P(A) + P(B) - 1+ P(C) - 1 \\ \geq P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - 2
$$

Hence, we are done. By induction, you can prove something similar for $n$ events $A_n$ also.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the characteristic function $1_S(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x\notin S\\1&\text{if }x\in S\end{cases}$.

You have $1_{S\cap T}=1_S\cdot 1_T$, from which the inequality $$1_{A\cap B\cap C}(x)=1_A(x)1_B(x)1_C(x)\ge 1_A(x)+1_B(x)+1_C(x)-2$$

But $$P(A\cap B\cap C)=E[1_{A\cap B\cap C}]\ge E[1_A+1_B+1_C-2]=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-2$$

**Added:** For the same reason, you can prove that $P\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k\right)\ge 1-n+\sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k)$